# doesntHave function not working eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to make use of the 'doesntHave' functionality with Laravel.

The idea is that I have a posts Queue and once a post is approved, it is removed from the Queue.

When the post is removed from the Queue- its means its approved and ready to show on the website, which is why I need to use whereHasNot to show the posts that aren't in queue (approved).

Unfortunately at the moment the Queue has an item and even though an item is present in the Queue, it is displaying on the web-page when it should be hidden.

[image]

What could be wrong?

**Queue Model:**

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Queue extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'queue';
    protected $primaryKey = null;
    public $timestamps = false;
    public $incrementing = false;
    public function parent(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Blog', 'url');
    }
}
```

**Blog Model:**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Blog extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'blog';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $incrementing = true;
    public function queue(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Queue', 'url');
    }
}
```

**Function where 'doesntHave' doesn't work.**

```
public function getPosts($feed, $amount){
    $posts = \App\Blog::doesntHave('queue')
    ->where('active', "=", 1)
    ->where('feed', '=', $feed)
    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
    ->limit($amount)
    ->get();
    foreach ($posts as $post){
        $post->post = $this->shortenPost($post->post);
    }
    return $posts;
    //Make first one large
}
```

**DDL Queue table:**

```
CREATE TABLE queue
(
    url VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    content_type VARCHAR(50),
    user_id INT(11),
    timestamp DATETIME
);
```

**Blog DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE blog
(
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title VARCHAR(200),
    url VARCHAR(150) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX blog_id_uindex ON blog (id);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX blog_url_uindex ON blog (url);
```

Comment: Hmm, can you explain a bit more clearly what's the problem? "Unfortunately at the moment the Queue is empty and even though an item is showing up in queue, it is displaying on the web-page as-well." <-- this part. If the queue is empty, the blog should be displayed on the web-page, no?

Comment: Did you try to do the `->get()` before the `->where('active', "=", 1)`?

Comment: Hi @devk - I've updated the question; apologies - its been a long day so my grammar is dying lol.
The main issue is that even though an item is in the queue it is showing up on the website when it should be hidden (i.e. not approved yet)

Comment: did you already double check data in the database?

Comment: How are the two tables connected? Via the `url` column?

Comment: There is no constraint between the two tables as multiple tables will share one queue - maybe will consider adding a table inbetween in the future

Comment: Added DDL's for reference.

Comment: @Wreigh data is definitely there - URL in one table = URL in next table. Even used a foreign key constraint to test before, worked fine